# java c++ jni unsatisfied link error

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm quite a newbie to Java JNI. I tried a helloCPP program but ran into problems. here's my code :

helloCPP.java;

```
public class helloCPP { 
    public native void hellocpp ();
    static { 
         System.loadLibrary("helloCPP");
     } 
    public static void main (String [] args) { 
         helloCPP hcpp=new helloCPP (); 
         hcpp.hellocpp (); 

         System.exit (0); 
     }
 }
```

Then here's my hellocpp.cpp out of which I made helloCPP.dll ;

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "helloCPP.h"
using namespace std ; 
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_helloCPP_hellocpp.  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
 cout <<"hello java, I'm c++\n";
}
int main (){};
```

I successfully built the helloCPP.dll.  But when I try to run java helloCPP, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: helloCPP.hellocpp () V
at helloCPP.hellocpp(Native Method) 
at helloCPP.main (helloCPP.java :8)
```

I'm doing all these stuff on a Windows 8 x86 operating system. 
These are the commands I wrote:

```
javac helloCPP.java 
javah helloCPP 
g++ -c hellocpp.cpp 
g++ -o helloCPP.dll hellocpp.cpp
```

This one generated the error:

```
java HelloCPP
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need a main() in a DLL, but you do need compiler and linker switches to specify producing a shared library.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely, the Java run-time cannot locate the DLL file. You have run the Java application with additional arguments (assuming the DLL file is in the current directory):

```
java -Djava.library.path=. HelloCPP
```

**Update:**

EJP has a good point. I think your link command isn't correct. The second g++ command should be something like:

```
g++ -o helloCPP.dll -shared hellocpp.o
```

There are two changes: `hellocpp.o` instead of `hellocpp.cpp` and more importantly the option `-shared` to indicate that you want to create a shared library and not an executable.

The exact options depend on your platform. As you haven't specified it, I can't tell you for sure.

Comment: I tried running that command on my cmd.exe but I still get the same same error message:

Comment: No. The exception tells you that the problem is in finding the method inside the DLL, which is already loaded.

Comment: thanks for the help. but I've tried running the g++ command for creating a shared library as you've advised above, I still get the same error message. definitely the dll is loaded but the native method is not being found. what do I need to do? please guys...

Comment: You need to tell us exactly on what platform you are. Then we can help you get the compile and link commands right. And we can help you debug your problem.

Comment: I'm using windows 8 pro x86. I built the .dll file using visual c++ and it has magically worked. I think the problem is on how we are supposed to create a "real" .dll file and not just some fake library with a .dll extension. So I guess that diverts us to another question....